# Training Deep Learning Model On Different Machine

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, data-science

Since I have low GPU resources, I wanna know how to train a deep learning model on multiple GPU on different machines.

I found this [link](https://github.com/horovod/horovod/blob/master/examples/keras_mnist.py)

But couldn't use it due to lack of proper documentation and heavy dependencies.
Please help me if anybody knows it.

Comment: you can try distributed deep learning with elephas, https://github.com/maxpumperla/elephas. This shows about single node configuration. For your case ,  you must have setup, Spark with master and different slave nodes (which I am not sure how to do).

Comment: multiple GPU in a single machine is possible using basic  Tensorflow code.

Comment: I think We can also use multiple machines each having GPU using Tensorflow, But I don't know how to implement it.